# Problema ao fazer um GET no meu site quando ele é entrado via www (react + django)

Tags: django, react, http-request, https, django-rest-framework

Possuo uma aplicação django que utiliza React em alguma de suas páginas (não são dois servers separados). Nas minhas páginas em React, eu faço requisições HTTP ao django pela api utilizando Django Rest Framework.

Essa aplicação já está no ar, e nela eu notei um problema. Caso eu entre no site sem "www", faça meu login normalmente e acesse as páginas via react, tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Porém, quando eu utilizo o "www" para acessar o site, primeiramente ele me faz refazer o login (não guarda que eu já estava logado) e também, ao acessar as páginas em react, a requisição GET dá o erro 403, que as credenciais não foram fornecidas, porém, sem o "www" funciona normalmente.

Segue dados sobre o DRF no settings.py:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

Realmente não sei se é problema do DRF, algo que ficou faltando na requisição, ou então algum problema do redirecionamento para HTTPS.

Alguém teria alguma ideia do que poderia ser? Obrigado!